# Replacing all instances of substring using a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I know there's a way to replace all instances that match some pattern like so: `re.sub(r'x', 'y', string)`.

But is there a way to replace all instances like `#a`, `#b`, with the values corresponding to the last character's values in a dictionary?

`dict = {'a': '1', 'b': 2', ... }`

so `abc#bcd#ae` becomes `abc2cd1e` and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `re.sub` (the replacement for any matches) can be a callable. If so, it's called with a single argument, the match object, for each match, and its result is substituted into the string. So you can do something like:

```
d = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
s = '#a #b and #c'
def replace_it(m):
    return d.get(m.group('key'), m.group(0))
print re.sub('#(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]+)', replace_it, s)
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the matching items found in the string:

```
mydict = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}
mystr = '#a#b'
for k, v in mydict.items():
    mystr = mystr.replace('#' + k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the exact things you want to replace, you don't need a regex.  Those are more for when you are looking for patterns, rather than exact matches.  string.replace should work for this.

```
string = "a#acbb#bd"
dictionary = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}
newstring1 = string.replace('#a', dictionary['a'])
newstring = newstring1.replace('#b', dictionary['b'])
print(newstring)
>>>a1cbb2d
```

Comment: True, but then you have to iterate through the string for every key in the dictionary. I was thinking there might be a way to get them all in one go and without loops.